# New user suggested edits need to be carefully reviewed

Tags: discussion

Today I have noticed some edits suggested by a new user are being approved by reviewers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117834/how-i-can-print-the-following-code

https://stackoverflow.com/users/3721860/user3721860?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24117850/revisions

When looking the edited posts, there are no improvements in the post.  The new user appears to be using the edit option to gain reputation.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: I assume the reputation gain for editing is intended to encourage cleaning up formatting, adding missing tags etc. Different users tend to specialize in different things. Is there really anything wrong with a new user deciding that the way they are going to contribute, and gain reputation, is editing, and doing a lot of it?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: OP is referring to cases where there is no improvement in the edits. check [this case for example](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2959925/nurealam11?tab=activity&sort=revisions)..absolutely no improvement in any of the edits made by the user

Comment: This guy mass adding **bold** to posts -.- http://stackoverflow.com/users/2168230/lavekush-agrawal?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: I would think that first link should be rolled back as it could be changing what the expected output that the OP is asking for

Comment: @OGHaza So it seems. Good job on those rollbacks. Now imagine if we had a working edit review system...

Comment: @JoeW It would get a rollback if there was anything of value in the question. But it is just a worthless code begging post, it should get nuked from the site. Nobody needs to waste time trying to edit the crap. But of course, if someone does edit it, they shouldn't vandalize the post.

Comment: @Lundin, I don't know how to imagine that

Answer (score 5):

It isn't exactly a black or white case. Some of those edits are just vandalism or nonsense, others are valid at some level.

But everyone wake up: the main problem here isn't the confused newbie trying to be helpful (for whatever reason), but *the poor quality of the edit reviews*. The confused newbie will eventually get sorted out automatically as his edits get rejected: he'll either learn and improve, or eventually get an automatic edit ban. The robo-edit reviewers that approve his posts is the real problem, which needs to be dealt with by a diamond mod.

So take the post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24117834/revisions for example, then flag it for diamond moderator attention, reason "Other". Write that the 5 people doing edit reviews approved of blatant vandalism and that they possibly need a ban from edit reviewing.

Comment: Agreed. I encountered the example in my answer during reviews, because robo-reviewers were constantly approving and I was unable to reject. After a few times, I had to take a closer look.

Comment: @Payeli A useful trick you can do when you see have clicked reject for an incorrect edit and then get "already approved". Click "skip" (there is nothing you can do to save the post from inside the edit review tool), then click the back-one-page on your web browser. It should now show all users that approved the post. For each user, check their review history. If it is 100% fishy accepts, you can flag the post for diamond mod attention and mention that the user is a robo-reviewer. This way you reduce the diamond mods work: they don't have to find the robot, but only decide what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for the trick. Will do that from now on :-)

Answer (score 4):

Flag any one of the posts as "Others (needs Moderator attention)".

I encountered [similar situation today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2959925/nurealam11?tab=activity&sort=revisions) where an user made lots of edits for reputation. So I flagged it for moderator attention with a custom message - "I am flagging to bring to your notice the last edit of this post. The Editor is constantly making invalid edits adding spurious tags, many of which are getting approved."

Comment: Which of the tags was spurious?  I only looked at a couple, that seemed OK.  Adding tags is actually useful (if they're relevant ones).

Comment: @SList: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24117079/revisions

Comment: @SList - [In this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24105754/revisions), "security" is incorrect tag (as per tag wiki of security) since this question has nothing to do with application security against software attacks

Comment: The first one is correct, surely?  It is not evil if he gets the odd one wrong.  Slightly annoying perhaps, but people do make mistakes.

Comment: Absolutely @SList, as Lundin's answer said, its the robo-reviewers, not the editor's mistake

Comment: Yes, I agree with that